Reload all page with experimental_fragments in streamlit
I have a problem with experimental_fragments in Streamlit. I wanted to create two graphs with two selection boxes, but the problem is that when I select one of these selection boxes it reloads the whole page. I copy you the code I used to understand where I went wrong. Thank you very much in advance for your response.
import streamlit as st
#import plotly as py 
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import pickle
import streamlit.components.v1 as components
import parsing_weekdate as pw
import plot as plt
import pandas as pd
import stype_font as sf
import calerror as ce
import time

if "reruns" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.reruns = 0

st.session_state.reruns += 1

fourweek= pd.read_csv('xxxxxx')
fourweek = fourweek.iloc[:-2,1:]
oneweek = pd.read_csv('xxxxxx')
oneweek = oneweek.iloc[:-2,1:]

#st.set_page_config(page_title=None, page_icon=None, layout="wide", initial_sidebar_state="collapsed", menu_items=None)
@st.experimental_fragment
def chart1():
    time.sleep(1)
    col4, col5, col6 = st.columns(3)

    with col6:
        option = st.selectbox(
            "Scegli la label di Analisi",
            ('naive','rf_noads','rf_isoweek_noads','rf_isoweek_prevsell_noads','rf_ads','rf_isoweek_ads','rf_isoweek_prevsell_ads'),
            key = 'fourweekcharts'
        )
    with col5:
        st.markdown(""" <style> .font2{
        font-size:30px ; font-family: 'Montserrat'; color: rgb(20,39,63);text-align: center} 
        </style> """, unsafe_allow_html=True)
        st.markdown('<p class="font2">1W Global Observation vs Forecast Values</p>', unsafe_allow_html=True)


    oneweekchart = ce.error(oneweek,'isoweek','observations',option)
    st.bokeh_chart(plt.plot_timeseries(oneweekchart),use_container_width=True)



@st.experimental_fragment
def chart2():
    time.sleep(1)
    col4, col5, col6 = st.columns(3)

    with col6:
        option = st.selectbox(
            "Scegli la label di Analisi",
            ('naive','rf_noads','rf_isoweek_noads','rf_isoweek_prevsell_noads','rf_ads','rf_isoweek_ads','rf_isoweek_prevsell_ads'),
            key = 'oneweek'
        )
    with col5:
        st.markdown(""" <style> .font2{
        font-size:30px ; font-family: 'Montserrat'; color: rgb(20,39,63);text-align: center} 
        </style> """, unsafe_allow_html=True)
        st.markdown('<p class="font2">1W Global Observation vs Forecast Values</p>', unsafe_allow_html=True)

    
    fourweekchart = ce.error(fourweek,'isoweek','observations',option)
    st.bokeh_chart(plt.plot_timeseries(fourweekchart),use_container_width=True)



with st.expander("Chart filtering 1 with fragment", expanded=True):
    with st.spinner("Crunching data..."):
        chart1()

with st.expander("Chart filtering 1 with fragment", expanded=True):
    with st.spinner("Crunching data..."):
        chart2()

I tried asking around how to solve the problem again, followed several tutorials but could not solve the problem
